# Как установить background и src в ImageView программно?

Tags: android

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему не задается цвет в ImageView src в адаптере?
У меня в setBackgroundResource рисуется шейп, а в setColorFilter должен цвет задаваться. setColorFilter в данном случае не работает!

```
//** Адаптер выбора цвета линий
private class ImageAdapter_colors_lines extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter_colors_lines(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mThumbIds[position];
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            int c; int d; //для перевода в dp
            c = (int) (mapsActivity.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density * 57); // типа dp
            d = (int) (mapsActivity.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density * 47); // типа dp
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(c, d));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
            int b1; int d1; //для перевода в dp
            b1 = (int) (mapsActivity.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density * 3); // типа dp
            d1 = (int) (mapsActivity.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density * 3); // типа dp
            imageView.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);

        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }



        imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.iv_gr_menu);
        imageView.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor(mThumbIds[position]));

        return imageView;
    }



    // Перечисляем цвета
    public String[] mColor_lines = {
            "#f5090d", "#00ff00", "#0000ff", "#ff00ff", "#a300ff",
            "#000000", "#000000", "#000000", "#000000", "#000000"
    };


    // Передаем из заолненого массива
    public String[] mThumbIds = mColor_lines;
}
```

Comment: У `setColorFilter` есть второй параметр, попробуйте разные значения.

Comment: PorterDuff.Mode... абсолютно ничего не дает..

Answer (score 0):

чтобы установить src программно, надо вызвать setImageResource(int), а не setBackgroundResource(int). Попробуйте изменить это и setColorFilter должен заработать.